# How to pass in additional parameters for the method after using promises with arrow functions?

Tags: typescript, ionic-framework, ionic2, arrow-functions

I'm new to Typescript and arrow functions. Trying to write the following in typescript but I'm getting confused about the 2nd parameter after the callback - "true".

```
FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
  // this will be called when the roundtrip to Facebook has completed
}, true);
```

This is what I have till now. I need help understanding why my placement of "true" is incorrect.

```
//Is the user already logged in ?
this.fb.getLoginStatus().then((response: any) => {
  //Do something       
  }, true); //Why is this incorrect?
```

Comment: Seems fine. Why do you think that it's incorrect? Do you get any errors? If so, what are they?

Comment: The `.then()` method accepts 2 arguments, both are expected to be functions: `then(success_callback, failure_callback)`. What you've done is pass `true` as the function that should be executed on error. Basically you did `getLoginStatus().then(callback).catch(true)`

Comment: These aren't the same at all. The first one provides two parameters. The second one provides no parameters.

Comment: Oh yeah, I didn't notice the `then`.  That's the problem

Comment: The second parameter indicates that you want to bypass the cache. I would definitely recommend that for login info.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like others are also facing this issue with the library I'm using ionic-native/facebook. I'm going to track the following open ticket on Github. Thanks for your help.

https://github.com/jeduan/cordova-plugin-facebook4/issues/315

Answer (score 1):

Why are you using then? Did the getLoginStatus method change? In your first example you pass the callback right into getLoginStatus.

This would be the exact same as your first example, just using a lambda.

```
this.fb.getLoginStatus((response: any) => {
  // this will be called when the roundtrip to Facebook has completed
}, true);
```

Comment: Thanks. I will use the direct callback. However if it were to return a promise - how would it look in code?

Comment: Actually, the ionic-native/facebook plugin that I'm using does define it as a Promise. My editor doesn't like the normal callback - it can't match any definitions for the method.

(method) Facebook.getLoginStatus(): Promise<any>

Answer (score 1):

This api takes two parameters - a callback and a flag indicating to hit the server and not use cached information.

I would definitely pass true for the second parameter since you likely don't want to use cached results to determine login information.

The callback doesn't appear to return a Promise object so you cannot use 'then' on it. It is a straight callback function that will return a response at some future point (ie. it is asynchronous).